# MPI_ERR_BUFFER: invalid buffer pointer

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi

What is the most common reason for this error

```
 MPI_ERR_BUFFER: invalid buffer pointer
```

which results from MPI_Bsend() and MPI_Rcev() calls?
The program works fine when the number of parallel processes is small (<14), but when I increase the number of processes I get this error.

Comment: Something is wrong with the buffer parameter.  Are you using `MPI_Buffer_attach`? I think you'll have to post some code to get more help.

Comment: Is there a maximum size for the buffer?

Comment: I don't think there is a size limit with `MPI_Buffer_attach` (other than the size of `int`).  The [MPI_Buffer_attach page](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/www/www3/MPI_Buffer_attach.html) says: "The size given should be the sum of the sizes of all outstanding Bsends that you intend to have, plus MPI_BSEND_OVERHEAD for each Bsend that you do. For the purposes of calculating size, you should use MPI_Pack_size."  Are you meeting these requirements?

Comment: With more processes to send to you end up with more data being buffered before it gets sent and your buffer is just too small. Increase its size or better use the non-blocking standard send `MPI_Isend()`.

Comment: @HristoIliev I used     MPI_Isend() and the problem was solved. You can post it as an anwer, and I will accept it.

Comment: I've posted a longer answer and I've tried to explain the problem and its solution in more details.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To expand on my previous comment:

Buffering in MPI can occur on various occasions. Messages can be buffered internally by the MPI library in order to hide the network latency (usually only done for small messages up to an implementation-dependent size) or buffering can be enforced by the user by using any of the buffered send operations `MPI_Bsend()` and `MPI_Ibsend()`. User buffering differs from the internal one though:

- first, messages sent by `MPI_Bsend()` or by `MPI_Ibsend()` are always buffered, which is not the case with internally buffered messages. The latter can either be buffered or not depending on their size and the availability of internal buffer space;
- second, because of the "always buffer" aspect, if no buffer space is available in the user attached buffer, an `MPI_ERR_BUFFER` error occurs.

Sent messages use buffer space until they are received for sure by the destionation process. Since MPI does not provide any built-in mechanisms to confirm the reception of a message, one has to devise another way to do it, e.g. by sending back a confirmation messages from the destination process to the source one.

For that reason one has to consider all messages that were not explicitly confirmed as being in transit and has to allocate enough memory in the buffer. Usually this means that the buffer should be at least as large as the total amount of data that you are willing to transfer plus the message envelope overhead which is equal to `number_of_sends * MPI_BSEND_OVERHEAD`. This can put a lot of memory pressure for large MPI jobs. One has to keep that in mind and adjust the buffer space accordingly when the number of processes is changed.

Note that buffered send is provided merely as a convenience. It could be readily implemented as a combination of memory duplication and non-blocking send operation, e.g. buffered send frees you from writing code like:

```
int data[];
int *shadow_data;
MPI_Request req;

...
<populate data>
...
shadow_data = (int *)malloc(sizeof(data));
memcpy(shadow_data, data, sizeof(data));
MPI_Isend(shadow_data, count, MPI_INT, destination, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &req);
...
<reuse data as it is not used by MPI>
...
MPI_Wait(&req);
free(shadow_data);
```

If memory is scarce then you should resort to non-blocking sends only.

Comment: Thanks Hirsto. Now using MPI_Isend in combination with MPI_Recv and MPI_Waitall, the program comes to halt (without producing error messages) when going to an even larger number of processes, simultaneously increasing the buffer sizes. There are great variance in the sizes of buffers sent by different processes. It still works fine for a smaller number of processes. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Could it be some peculiar behaviour of your MPI implementation? What MPI library are you using and what hardware (mainly whay interconnect?). Could it be that something in your algorithm goes wrong? It might help if you have access to a parallel debugger like DDT or TotalView.

Comment: The problem turned out to be somewhere else. Thanks!